# Python pandas Pivot table object

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

is it possible to output a pivoted dataframe to excel with the benefits of the interactive pivot panel in excel?
When inserting a pivot table in excel, we get this panel. What i want is that I also want this panel when I write my pivot table in excel

[image: Pivot table panel in excel]

Im using `pd.ExcelWriter` to write in my excel sheet.

Comment: No. Pandas cannot write formulas or really anything more complicated than raw data to Excel. ... Just export your raw data and create a Pivot table with it in Excel.

Comment: Agree wuth @BeRT2me, it isn't possible with pandas. If you want to go hard way, quick searching brings me alternative variant here  https://trenton3983.github.io/files/solutions/2020-06-22_pivot_table_win32com/create_pivot_table_with_win32com.html
So if your are on Windows and able to run excel on the same machine, you can do this with generated excel via pywin32